# Optimization cats library "<*>"

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am trying to optimize imports in my code and eliminate all `"_"` as `import cats.implicits._`

I have already optimized all my imports except the cats simbol `"<*>"`. I tryed with:

```
import cats.Apply.Ops
import cats.Apply.{A,lot,of,options}
import cats.implicits.{A,lot,of,options}
import cats.syntax.ApplyOps
...
```

With `import cats.implicits._` my code works perfectly.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `import cats.syntax.apply._`

Comment: Thank you. the best solution is: `import cats.syntax.apply.catsSyntaxApply`

Comment: @PabloLópezGallego Normally implicits are imported like `import somepackage.someobject._` where `someobject` is the object containing necessary implicit. Normally you don't resolve implicits manually.